# Huge size for main.js file in Angular project build

Tags: angular

I'm trying to deploy my Angular application but I see it takes around 60s to load first page contents.
I see that the main.js file size is > 6MB which is huge number.
I run command `ng build --prod` for building.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of dependencies in your `app.module.ts` it is logical to have a huge bundle size.

You should read [angular-bundle-size-optimization](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/optimize-angular-bundle-size-in-4-steps-4a3b3737bf45) to help you reduce the size.

A basic Angular application should be less then 3mb to be easily downloaded on bad networks, but it always depends on the clients of your application.

`Reduce unnecessary dependencies` and `Use Lazy Loaded modules` are the first steps to reduce the large bundle size. [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) is also useful to detect where the problem is as it analyses the size of every file of your build.